# Limiting photos with `@photos.last(5)` isn't working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This code doesn't throw any errors, but no photos appear. The `<div>` around the code is empty when I check in inspect element. If I change `@user.photos.last(5)` to `@user.photos.each`, the photos appears. But I want to show only 5 of the most recently added photos.

```
<%- @user.photos.last(5) do |photo| %>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3 no-padding">
    <a href="<%= user_photo_path(@user.username, photo.id) %>" class="photo-thumbnail">
      <%= image_tag photo.url %>
    </a>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Please take some time to go though documentation once again. it is just a minor problem.

```
<%- @user.photos.last(5).each do ....
```

Comment: I would add to this that `last(5)` returns an array, so you need to iterate through that array for the block to run as expected. Without `each`,  `|photo|` just represents the entire array and the resulting block won't work.

Comment: Without `each` the block is ignored as `last` has no use for it.